# Retrieve all value pairs from List<Integer>

Tags: java, string, list

For example I have a `List<Integer>`  object with the following:

```
3, 6, 5, 3, 3, 6
```

The result would be 3 and 6. How can I create a function that tests for duplicates and then returns 1 value of the duplicate (not the pair, just one in the pair)? One problem that might occur is if there are quadruple values: `3, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 3` Then I would like to return 3 and 3. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does the output order have to be *stable*, meaning that the pairs are output in the same order in which they appear in the input? In particular, would it violate your intended contract to emit `[ 6, 3 ]` given your sample input?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just have to display 3 and 6 in whatever order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go through the list counting the number of instances of each one (storing them in a map) and then create a new list from the map:

```
List<Integer> values = // the list of values you have
Map<Integer,Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

for(Integer value : values) {
    if(counts.containsKey(value)) {
        counts.put(value, counts.get(value)+1);
    } else {
        counts.put(value, 1);
    }
}

List<Integer> resultValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(Integer value : counts.keySet()) {
    Integer valueCount = counts.get(value);
    for(int i=0; i<(valueCount/2); i++) { //add one instance for each 2
        resultValues.add(value);
    }
}
return resultValues;
```

This avoids the O(nlogn) behavior of sorting the values first, working in O(n) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think the "map" way by @RHSeeger is good enough.  Here I just suggest another way, just for 'fun', so that u may take a look.  It kind of give a stable result: first completed pairs appears first:

```
List<Integer> values = ....;
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Set<Integer> unpairedValues = new HashSet<Integer>();

for (int i : values) {
  if (unpairedValues.contains(i)) {
    result.add(i);
    unpairedValues.remove(i);
  } else {
    unpairedValues.add(i);
  }
}
// result contains what u want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// ArrayList<Integer> list = {3, 6, 5, 3, 3, 6}
Collections.sort(list);

ArrayList<Integer> pairs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int last = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  // some value that will never appear in the list
for (Integer cur : list) {
    if (last == cur) {
        pairs.add(cur);
        last = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  // some value that will never appear in the list
    } else {
        last = cur;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pairs.toArray()));
```

Will output

```
[3, 6]
```

** **Edit** **

Slightly better algorithm, modifies the given list

```
// ArrayList<Integer> list = {3, 6, 5, 3, 3, 6}
Collections.sort(list);
int index = 1, last;
while (index < list.size()) {
    last = list.remove(index - 1);
    if (list.get(index - 1) == last) {
        index++;
    }
    if (index == list.size()) {
        list.remove(index - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way in pseudo code:

```
sortedList = sort (list)
duplicates = empty list
while (length (list) > 1)
{
    if (list [0] == list [1] )
    {
         duplicates.append (list [0] )
         list.removeAt (0)
    }
    list.removeAt (0);
}
```